# jquery popup dosent iterating for Models values in Django

Tags: html, ajax, django, jquery-ui

Jquery Popup doesn't iterate for model values in Django application, only the last value from query set it popup for all button.

QuerySet values which are rendering from model to template via views are as below:

```
<QuerySet [<CheckList: Feeds (S/N/L)>, <CheckList: EU/NY feeds>, <CheckList: EPSCPORT Feeds>, <CheckList: 9:00 AM IST time  should be compeleted>, <CheckList: PL fees>, <CheckList: LOAD job should be completed>, <CheckList: Check all FD job status>, <CheckList: Cut off job should be completed>, <CheckList: Do the Health checks>, <CheckList: Check the Statement generation>, <CheckList: Check Service now tickets>, <CheckList: Check application status>, <CheckList: Perform the ELT health checks>]>
```

The home.html  file looks like:

```
 {% include 'header.html' %}  
 {% load static %}

 {% include 'snippets/external.js' %} 
 {% include 'snippets/nav.html' %}  
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.css" />

                <body>
        <!--  -->
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Expected Time</th>
          <th>SLA Time</th>
          <th>Application</th>
          <th>Check Discription</th>
          <th>Check Details</th>
          <th>Task Handle by</th>
          <th>Completed time</th>
          <th>Start Effort</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

    {% for i in query_set %}    
                <tr>
                <td><small class="text-muted d-block">{{  i.expected_time }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="text-muted d-block">{{  i.sla_time }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="text-muted d-block">{{  i.app_name }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="text-muted d-block">{{  i.check_discription }}</small></td>


                <td class="align-middle">

                    <button class="w2ui-btn" onclick="popup()">
                    <img src="{% static "file.png" %}" alt=" width="30" height="30"/></button>

                </td>

                <td class="align-middle">{{ user.get_username }}</td>

                <td class="align-middle"><h4 id="timer"><b> 00 : 00 </b></h4></td>

                <td class="align-middle">
                <button id="start" type="submit"><img src="{% static "play.png" %}" alt=" width="20" height="20"/></button>

                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">

                    <button id="stop" type="submit"><img src="{% static "stop.png" %}" alt=" width="20" height="20"/></button>

                </td>           </tr>


        <script type="text/javascript">


        function popup() {
                w2popup.open({
                    title     : '{{ i.app_name }}',
                    body      : '<div class="w2ui-centered">{{ i.check_discription }}</div>',
                    buttons   : '<button class="w2ui-btn" onclick="w2popup.close();">Close</button> '+
                                '<button class="w2ui-btn" onclick="w2popup.lock(\'Loading\', true); '+
                                '        setTimeout(function () { w2popup.unlock(); }, 2000);">Lock</button>',
                    width     : 500,
                    height    : 300,
                    overflow  : 'hidden',
                    color     : '#333',
                    speed     : '0.3',
                    opacity   : '0.8',
                    modal     : true,
                    showClose : true,
                    showMax   : true,
                    onOpen    : function (event) { console.log('open'); },
                    onClose   : function (event) { console.log('close'); },
                    onMax     : function (event) { console.log('max'); },
                    onMin     : function (event) { console.log('min'); },
                    onKeydown : function (event) { console.log('keydown'); }
                });             }

            </script>

            {% endfor %}        
</tbody>
```

Now the issue is, when I click on the Popup Button with Image TEXT.PNG it give me the last value from  the query set. How to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by passing variable inside popup function it works.

```
<td class="align-middle">
        <!--    <input type="text" value="{{  i.app_name }}">  -->
                <button class="w2ui-btn" onclick="popup('{{  i.check_discription }}' , '{{  i.note }}')">

                <img src="{% static "file.png" %}"  width="30" height="30" />

                </button>

            </td>
```